# Why does Spark call "main" instead of using an interface like "SparkJob"?

Tags: apache-spark

Spark calls the main method on the specified class, and that main method is expected to construct a SparkContext or SparkSession.  Configuration not specified explicitly, like master URL, will come from properties passed in on the command line or from configuration files.

What I'm wondering about: why does Spark look for a `main` method instead of using an interface like `SparkJob` with a `run` method that takes `SparkSession` as an injected argument?  This is a common convention with other forms of managed code that run inside a container; you could still have a `main` method to construct and inject a `SparkSession` in local mode for unit testing.

In other words why not this

```
public class MySparkJob implements SparkJob {
  public void run(SparkSession spark) {
  }
}
```

instead of this:

```
public class MySparkJob {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     SparkSession spark = ...
  }
}
```